# Which input type is this?

Tags: html

I don't know which type of input this is, What do I have to put in the `type=""`?

[image: image of the input type]

Comment: no, the input field, so the whole thing in the pic

Comment: that's probably a `select` with [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)

Comment: this in select box not input

Comment: Tip: your browser has developer tools. Use them to "inspect" that input, which leads you to its HTML

Answer (score 3):

Drop down menus can be created in `HTML` using the `select` and `option` tags. The format looks something along the lines of this:

```html
<select name="foo">
   <option value="int">INT</option>
   <option value="varchar">VARCHAR</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is a `select` input with `optgroup` being used.

```html
<label for="dino-select">Choose a dinosaur:</label>
<select id="dino-select">
    <option>Tyrannosaurus</option>
    <option>Diplodocus</option>
    <optgroup label="Theropods">
        <option>Tyrannosaurus</option>
        <option>Velociraptor</option>
        <option>Deinonychus</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sauropods">
        <option>Diplodocus</option>
        <option>Saltasaurus</option>
        <option>Apatosaurus</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Check out the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) for it.